# React web navigation based on anchors

Tags: reactjs, scroll, react-router, anchor, single-page-application

I'm trying to setup a *single page* react web application. My application only has one page with all the components places one after the other, so, the common react-router solution that lets you render only some part of the application doesn't work for me.

The intention is to have only one page (as large as it becomes) and the user can navigate between sections on it through a menu (or similar). Also, the site should recognize when someone types the URL like `http://url.com/#section4`, and scroll automatically to the requested section, marking the selected section on the menu as active.

Also, like a nice to have, it would be awesome if the URL can change depending on page scroll.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-hash-link) that works in conjunction with the React Router's BrowserRouter, and allows to have a based anchor navigation, and also customize the scroll function were you can put offset or anything you wan to. Something like this:

```
<NavHashLink to="#anchor1" scroll={el => this.scroll(el)}>Anchor1</NavHashLink>

  scroll (el) {
    const offset = document.getElementById('element').offsetHeight
    window.scrollTo({ top: el.offsetTop - offset, left: 0, behavior: 'smooth' })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should either use *HashRouter* from **react-router-dom** package, or you can use a *NavLink* from the same package like this:

```
<NavLink>  
    to="/foo/#bar"  
    isActive={()=> window.location.pathname + window.location.hash === "/foo/#bar"}  
</NavLink>
```